# Remove word from the end of a string that has been cut off to different lengths

Tags: regex, perl

So let's say I have a list of strings which sometimes end with a phrase that has been cut off to different lengths. In this example the phrase is "hello".

```
my @strings =
(
    "Test 1 hello",
    "Something else",
    "Test 2 hell",
    "And also he",
    "Test 4 hel"
);
```

This is how I would remove the "hello" fragments right now:

```
foreach my $string (@strings)
{
    if ($string =~ m/(.*?)\s*(h(e(l(lo?)?)?)?)?$/)
    {
        print "'", $string, "' -> '", $1, "'\n";
    }
}
```

It does work:

```
'Test 1 hello' -> 'Test 1'
'Something else' -> 'Something else'
'Test 2 hell' -> 'Test 2'
'And also he' -> 'And also'
'Test 4 hel' -> 'Test 4'
```

However, I find the regular expression to match all the "hello" fragments long, confusing and hard to modify for future use cases.
Is there a shorter way to write something equivalent to `(h(e(l(lo?)?)?)?)?$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to build the regex is an alternation of possible string versions. This I think should also extend well to more general uses

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $target = shift || 'hello';

my @strings = (
    "Test 1 hello",
    "Something else",
    "Test 2 hell",
    "And also he",
    "Test 4 hel"
);

my $re_versions = build_regex($target);

foreach my $string (@strings)
{
    if ($string =~ /($re_versions)$/)
    {
        say "'$string' --> $1";
    }
};

sub build_regex {
    my ($s) = @_;
    my @versions;
    while ($s) {
        push @versions, quotemeta $s;
        chop $s;
    }
    return join '|', @versions;
}
```

This isn't shorter (while it certainly *can* be written in a shorter way) but it should be manageable for refinements in acceptable versions of the string, matching order, etc.

If there is a reason to want a compiled regex back change the function return to

```
my $re_str = join '|', @versions;
return qr/$re_str/;
```

where you can now also add flags that may be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a regexp to match following expressions *at end of a string* : `hello`, `hell`, `hel`, `he`, `h`. We can expect that the expression is preceeded by at least once space.

You could just write :

```
s/\s+(hello$)|(hell$)|(hel$)|(he$)|(h$)// for @strings;
```

This will modify in-place all elements in the array to what you expect.

I needed, you can generate the match string automatically for any given word :

```
my $word  = "hello";
my @parts = map { substr $word, 0, $_ } (1..(length $word));
my $match = join "|", map { "(" . $_ . "\$)" } @words;
s/\s+$match// for @strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

dawg's answer simplifies the regex but it doesn't work for use cases that are more complex than my example. GMB's answer works in any case but also leads to long (but admittedly better understandable) regexes. My personal solution is to use a function to construct the correct regex dynamically from any needed string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings =
    (
        "Test 1 hello",
        "Something else",
        "Test 2 hell",
        "And also he",
        "Test 4 hel"
    );

my $regex = cutOffStringRegex('hello');

foreach my $string (@strings)
{
    if ($string =~ m/(.*?)\s*$regex$/x)
    {
        print "'", $string, "' -> '", $1, "'\n";
    }
}

sub cutOffStringRegex
{
    my ($string) = @_;
    my $resultString = "";
    if (length($string) == 1)
    {
        $resultString = quotemeta $string;
    }
    else
    {
        my $firstChar = quotemeta(substr $string, 0, 1);
        my $rest = substr $string, 1;
        $resultString = $firstChar . cutOffStringRegex($rest);
    }
    return '(' . $resultString . ')?';
}
```

`cutOffStringRegex('hello')` results in `"(h(e(l(l(o)?)?)?)?)?"`.
Since my question was "how to write this shorter", I won't mark this answer as the correct one because it definitly isn't shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You  could use  a reverse  logic: instead  of searching  for
partial `hello`s, grab the last  word and search for it *in*
`hello`.

Maybe this won't be exactly  shorter, but it can be cleaner.
Grabbing the last word is easy enough with a `/(\w+)$/`, and
to check if it is contained in `hello` no regex is needed. A
simple call to `index` will do.

```
foreach (@strings) {
    (my $original = $_) =~ /(\w+)$/;
    s/\s*\w+$// unless index('hello', $1);
    say "'$original' -> '$_'";
}
```

To make it clear, `index` returns the index of the substring
`$1`  in `'hello'`.  We only  care  about the  case when  it
returns  0, meaning  it exists  and is  at the  start (would
be  -1 if  non-existent  or  bigger than  0  at a  different
position). That's why we remove the last word only when this
operation is 0 with `unless`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the fragments of starting with `he` with that being an optional fragment:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.020;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings =
(
    "Test 1 hello",
    "Something else",
    "Test 2 hell",
    "And also he",
    "Test 4 hel"
);

for (@strings){
    s/\hhe[lo]*$//;
    say;
}
```

Prints:

```
Test 1
Something else
Test 2
And also
Test 4
```

Or, you can match and keep what you want:

```
for (@strings){
    say $1 if /^(.*?)(?:\hhe[lo]*)?$/;
}
# same output
```

If you want to make sure that the captured text matches the characters `hello` in that order, match the captured substring:

```
for (@strings){
    say if /^(.*?)( he[lo]*)?$/ && (!$2 || ' hello' =~ /^$2/);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't want to filter the strings but to remove the 'hello' fragments.

Comment: @BenjaminKrupp: Edited.

Comment: Can it end with just an "h" or "helo" or "heo", etc. ?  Then does  this regex work?

Comment: As I understood the desire, it was `he[letters that look like hello]*` so the mark is `\h` + `he`.